# How can I change the class W1 into W2

Tags: jquery, html, css

Situation:
You can make a div bigger or smaller depending if you plus or minus with 1 week.

CSS

```
.w1{width: 32px;}
.w2{width: 64px;}
.w3{width: 96px;}
.etc...
```

HTML

```
<div class="js-main-item">
    <span class="js-week" data-week="-1">-1 week</span>
    <span class="js-week" data-week="1" >+1 week</span>
    <div class="js-week-activity w1">Activity</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('click','.j-week',function(e){   
    //Get the number (+ or -1)
    var number =$(this).attr('data-week');
    //Select the class wX
    //Get the X and add the number to it
});
```

How do I get the jQuery working?

I have to work with these 2 conditions.

1. Sometimes the class is w2 or w3, depending on how the div is
   rendered by PHP
2. Also the width of 32px is flexible. The user can
   choose 3 sizes. Sometimes W1 represents 100px. Sometimes it
   represents 200px; The CSS is rendered by PHP.

Comment: Don't use `a` if you're not linking anything. Use a span or a button instead. If you need the cursor to change on hover, add `cursor: pointer;` to the css of that element.

Comment: Thanks, I will change the example

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.js-week').click(function(){

    var w = ($(this).attr("data-week") === '-1') ? -32 : +32;

    var curWidth = $('.w1').width();

    //If you want maximum 96px
    //w = ((curWidth + w) > 96 ) ? 0 : w;

    $('.w1').width(curWidth + w);

  })

})
```

```css
.w1 {width: 32px;border: 2px solid orange; transition: all 500ms linear; margin-top: 10px;}

.j-week {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-main-item">

  <a class="js-week" data-week="-1" href="#">-1 week</a> / 

  <a class="js-week" data-week="1" href="#">+1 week</a>

  <div class="js-week-activity w1">Activity</div>

</div>
```